# Intercepting the home button in a floating window

Tags: android

When using a floating view (`TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE`) how can the Home button be intercepted?

This behaviour is demonstrated in Facebook's "chat heads" where a conversation (which isn't an Activity) is collapsed on a home button click.

Comment: no, home button cannot be intercepted

Comment: @pskink, How does fb messenger work? It doesn't look like there's an open activity there.

Answer (score 0):

You could poll the top running app, and determine when it changes. This will detect the first home press, but if the users is already on the home screen, you will not detect it.